# sql parser to fetch all columns used in the sql query

Tags: java, string

I am trying to parse sql query e.g-update,delete,insert & merge, i am

using below snippet to manipulate the sql query:

```
   if (nativeQuery.contains("UPDATE")) {
        //"nativeSQL": "UPDATE test.abcSET first_name = ?,last_name = ? WHERE product_id = ?"
        queryArray = nativeQuery.split(" ");
        table = queryArray[1].split("\\.")[1];
        
        String s = StringUtils.substringAfter(nativeQuery, "SET");
        s = s.replaceAll("WHERE | AND", "");
        
    } else if (nativeQuery.contains("insert")) {
        //"nativeSQL": "insert into test.xyz(product_id,first_name,last_name) values(?,?,?)"
        queryArray = nativeQuery.split(" ");
        table = queryArray[2].split("\\.")[1];
        
    }
```

any suggestion to parse the columns from queries? the way i am trying , it needs more string manipulation .Please suggest any efficient way to do the same

Comment: Writing your own SQL parser is a very daunting task.  You might want to look into some of the JDBC APIs, to see if they perhaps can give you the metadata about a query you are seeking.

Comment: correct but i don't see any option with jdbc api, can you highlight any such api if you are aware?

Comment: To understand a small bit of the task you're attempting to take, look at the [syntax of update clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This is SQL Server since you haven't mentioned any RDBM, but you would need to take into account CTEs, from clause, variables can also be updated, columns might be inside functions, database / table prefixes, escaping the columns, etc

Comment: I am looking for some better solution to approach this can you suggest